# Fade out images in order

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is basically a mathematical question, would like to know what would be a good solution.

Problem: I have 25 images placed in one line. I want the images to fade out in the order. That is the first image should be completely opaque and last image should be completely transparent.
I have placed all these images in an order inside one parent.

My solution: I am just providing a fixed number that iterates itself for the alpha.

What I am looking for: a formula so that this "fixed" number can be dynamically changed by number of images present.

```
void Start () {

        int color = 10; //my fixed number

        foreach (Transform child in transform) {

                child.gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color32(255, 255, 255, (byte) (255 - color));
                color += 10; //iterating for the next child
            }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about simply calculating the step:

```
void Start () 
{
    if(transform.childCount <= 1)
    {
        Debug.LogWarning("Requires at least 2 children!");
        return;
    }

    var alphaStep = 1f / (transform.childCount - 1);
    var alpha = 1f;
    foreach (Transform child in transform) 
    {
        child.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, alpha);
        alpha -= alphaStep;     
    }
}
```

Or if you want full control over the maximum and minimum alpha you could use e.g.

```
public float minAlpha = 0f;
public float maxAlpha = 1f;
```

and then

```
var alphaStep = 1f / (transform.childCount - 1);
for (var i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++) 
{
    var factor = i / (transform.childCount - 1);
    transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(1f, 1f, 1f, Mathf.Lerp(maxAlpha, minAlpha, factor));    
}
```

Comment: that is brilliant :) however, it is in reverse order currently, can it be from completely opaque to less and less transparent? Also is it possible that the last image is not completely transparent but still has bit of transparency left?

Comment: @Vika of course ... for a) just invert and rather start with `alpha = 1f;` and then do `alpha -= alphaStep;` .. for b) just e.g. do not do `1f / ( transform.childCount - 1)` but e.g. `1f / (transform.childCount)`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use an Array to iterate over your elements more freely.

With that you could go something like... (*coding in SO, not tested*)

```
Image[] images; // this should reference the array constructed elsewhere where you load the images.

private void Start() {
    for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++) {
        int alpha = 255 - (Mathf.CeilToInt(255 / images.Length) * i + 1);
        images[i].color = Color32(255,255,255,alpha);}
}
```

That will probably do what you want.

By the way, not sure why you using Color32 but working with "float" RGBA will rid you from that ceil and give you more precision.